# Python load tempfile as module

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I can't seem to load a `tempfile` with contents using `importlib`. It works fine if I have the content saved under a python file (with .py extension), then provide that file path.

Is there a way to make the importlib work with a tempfile?

For reference, see the sample code below:

```
import importlib
import importlib.util
import tempfile


with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False) as tf:
    tf.write("""
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
""")
    tf.seek(0)

    file_path = tf.name

    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("script", file_path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    t = getattr(module, "Test", None)
    print(t)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("script", file_path)
spec is None

```
import importlib
import importlib.util
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False) as tf:
    tf.write("""
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
""")
    tf.seek(0)

    file_path = tf.name

    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("script", file_path)
    print(f'{spec=}')
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    t = getattr(module, "Test", None)
    print(t)
```

Comment: Yea I know.  How do you make it work and not be None?